# Unable to read messages sent by server

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, client-server, ipc

I have a server client connection and I am trying to read the messages sent by the server. The code I used in the main function works, but when I try to read the messages in a thread, it doesn't read anything. This is the code I am using:

```
newsockfd = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

sock_desc = malloc(1);
*sock_desc = newsockfd; 

//create a new thread
pthread_t client_thread;
if(pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, thread_function, (void *)sock_desc)<0)
     error("ERROR creating thread!");

//thread function
void *thread_function(void * sock_desc){

//get the socket descriptor
int sock = *(int*)sock_desc;
printf("sock %d\n", sock);
int n;

printf("New thread\n");
fflush(stdout);

bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sock,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

return (void *)0;

}//close thread_function()
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Indentation...............

Comment: What output do you see?

Comment: 'sock_desc = malloc(1);' - int won't fit.

Comment: All those casts are very confusing............

Comment: You malloc the (badly sized), storage for 'sock_desc', but don't free it at the end of the client<>server thread, so it leaks.

Comment: In client code, there isn't much point in performing the connect on the loader thread and then offloading the fd to the thread.  It makes more sense to malloc a struct for the serv_addr, signal that to the thread and perform the connect() in the thread.

Comment: After the connect() and pthread_create(), what does the loader thread do?

Comment: The read() in the thread is not looped and so may well not read all the data sent by the server in the one call.

Comment: The read thread does not seem to close() the 'sock' before exiting, so leaking it.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit *`sock_desc = malloc(1);` - int won't fit.*  No, it doesn't fit. But it likely isn't causing a problem here. Since `malloc()` *et al* have to return memory "suitably aligned for any purpose", `malloc()` implementations tend to effectively return memory in something like 8- or 16-byte increments.  So while it's not correct at all to try stuffing a 4-byte `int` into a 1-byte chunk of `malloc()`'d memory, the "undefined behavior" in this case is probably "eh, it didn't mess anything up so it worked OK".  It's *wrong* but it likely didn't *break* anything here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, that's what I suspected, but still, needs fixing and/or pointing out to avoid confusing future users:)

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Saying "it doesn't read anything": is a useless statement without the code to know what else is going on.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I assumed *you* did - but the questioner seems new to writing C code and it can be helpful to understand why overrunning a `malloc()`'d buffer can sometimes appear to be OK.

Comment: @AndrewHenle all true - the OP may be trying to follow all that dubious advice like 'To keep your code clean and readable, you should call free() in the same procedure in which you call malloc()', (from an 'educational' site!).  I wouldn't be surprised if the OP is closing the fd in the loader before the thread can use it...

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Do they really teach that kind of crap?  Ugh. What's the point of `malloc()` in that case?  Just use a local variable.  Available stack size on single-threaded programs is about the same as available heap size.  And if you don't know how much memory your code uses - and where - you're coding on hope anyway.

Comment: I am freeing the memory allocated by malloc and closing the socket afterwards.. Thanks, allocation 4 bytes helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in comments, your allocation is wrong, but

```
    newsockfd = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

is *the* problem. `connect` does not return new socket. It returns a success/failure status. You should

```
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        handle_connection_error();
    } else {
        pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, thread_function, (void *)&sockfd);
    }
```